Size of types implementing a trait
I want to define a slice of MaybeUninit of trait objects, something like [MaybeUnint<dyn MyTrait>;2]. Of course, this doesn't work because Rust doesn't know the size of a dyn MyTrait at compile time. So my question is, is there a way to require the types implementing a trait be of a certain size? e.g. so anything that implements MyTrait takes up 4 bytes?
Link to the playground
In response to @AleksanderKrauze's comment: I'm trying to build a "composable" memory memory allocator. I have a struct ChunkAllocator<CHUNK_SIZE> that allocates in fixed-sized chunks, and I want to store a few of them in a slice to create an allocator that can allocate different sizes. So they are all implementing the same trait (Allocator) and have the same size (or at least I can bound it) but the type signature is different. I'd like to keep the allocation size as part of the type rather than move it to a field inside the struct.

This is likely a XY-problem. Please state what you are actually trying to do.

Why do you want to have a MaybeUninit<dyn Foo> in the first place?

It is possible to write a "Box on the stack" type (and such implementations exist), but it will require nightly for proper unsizing support (although there are hacks) and even for proper soundness.

@ChayimFriedman I'm already using nightly so that's not a problem. Do you maybe have a link to such implementation?

But why do you want to have MaybeUninit<ChunkAllocator as dyn Allocator>? Why allocator itself is uninitialised?

@AleksanderKrauze each ChunkAllocator manages a page of fixed size, and I want to decide the size chunks I will allocate from that page during runtime

That sounds like a ChunkAllocator should contain MaybeUninit<Chunk> (or an array/vector thereof) not like it should be a MaybeUninit<ChunkAllocator>

@14159 that doesn't really explain why allocator itself is not of fixed size.

I wasn't able to find a crate that uses nightly, all target stable... But here's a simple one: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2ebe29e0a9b9f4084186c3611d774015.
